# A Detail on a Proof of a Lemma to the Hahn Decomposition Theorem.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In the highlighted line of the proof, the author argues that $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ for sufficiently large $i$, while it seems to me that the inequality $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ should hold for all $i$, since

$$E\subseteq P = A\ /\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_i\right) \subseteq A\ / \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)$$

so that $\nu(E)$ is in the set that $\delta_i$ is the infinum of, implying $\delta_i\le\nu(E)$.

Am I wrong? If so, what am I missing?

[image: First part of the proof]

[image: Second part of the proof]

---

The question may seem silly since I do agree on the result being proven, but not being able to follow the author's steps makes me worry that my reasoning (and thus my understanding of the proof) is wrong, hence why I feel the need to ask.

In case it's needed, the proof is from John K. Hunter's [notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes.pdf) on Measure Theory.

Comment: I think you are right $\nu(E)\geq \delta_i$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $\nu(E) \geq \delta_i$ for all $i$ for the reason you've shown.
Here is a potential reason why the author of the proof could have worded it that way.

1. It is sufficient to know that $\nu(E) \geq \delta_i$ for every sufficiently large $i$ to claim that $\nu(E) \geq 0$ (in fact even weaker statement that the inequality is valid on an infinite subsequence of $\delta_i$ would suffice). Hence, we do not need to show it for every $i$ for the proof.
2. From the beginning of the proof there were two cases: (a) $\delta_i > -\infty$ and (b) $\delta_i = -\infty$. Case (b) is a bit annoying: we could show that it never happens, but that would require a bit extra work. The author argues that this can only happen for finitely many $i$. Therefore, from that point on we could just ignore those values of $i$ (see the observation 1. above). That allows us to only deal with case (a) and forget about (b).
3. Hence, the following (highlighted) argument is made for $i$ except those finitely many values.